# Get record ids from groups where the sum of one of the field of their records is greater than

Tags: sql, group-by, having-clause

I have records as such:

```
    Id  ForeignKey  Level   ValueA  ValueB
    1   1001        1       2       10
    2   1001        1       10      10
    3   1001        1       20      20
    4   1001        2       20      30
    5   1002        1       1       100
    6   1003        1       1       100
    7   1004        1       1       100
```

I want to get the Ids of each record of the groups grouped by ForeignKey and Level where the sum of the group's records' ValueA values divided by the sum of ValueB values is greater than 0.5

In this case, I'd like to retrieve the Id of the three first records as (2 + 10 + 20) / (10 + 10 + 20) = 0.8

Here is what I've got so far:

```
    select 
    ForeignKey,
    SUM(ValueA) as ValueASum,
    SUM(ValueB) as ValueBSum,
    from tableA 
    group by ForeignKey
    having (SUM(ValueA) / SUM(ValueB) > 0.5)
```

The result is

```
    ForeignKey  ValueASum   ValueBSum
    1001        32          40
```

How do I get the ids of the records from this point? If I add the Id in the select, I must group on it and then have a group for each record.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, how about

```
select id from your_table where foreignkey = 1001
```

Is something wrong with working with multiple queries?

If you want you can do a subquery:

```
select id from your_table where foreignkey in ( select foreignkey from ( <yourQuery> ) sq);
```

UPDATE:

```
select t.id from Table1 t
inner join 
( 
    select 
    ForeignKey, level,
    SUM(ValueA) as ValueASum,
    SUM(ValueB) as ValueBSum
    from Table1 
where level = 1
    group by ForeignKey, Level
    having (SUM(ValueA) / SUM(ValueB) > 0.5) ) sq
ON t.foreignkey = sq.foreignkey AND t.level = sq.level
```

I added `where level = 1` just because your given resultset not what I get when I execute your query.

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b956c/11/0).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I can't do that.I edited my question, hope this clears out the fact that I can't simply query on the ForeignKey. For one ForeignKey, there might be more than one levels, I need to group on ForeignKey and on Level. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @G.Abitbol Feel free to accept my answer, as it's the same as DRapp's and I had to clear up the question first (and I was earlier) :)

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, but if you wanted it from each "Level", you would need to add that into your group by also.

```
select
      tA2.ID,
      tA2.ForeignKey,
      tA2.Level,
      tA2.ValueA,
      tA2.ValueB
   from
      ( select 
              tA.ForeignKey,
              tA.Level,
              SUM(tA.ValueA) as ValueASum,
              SUM(tA.ValueB) as ValueBSum,
           from 
              tableA tA
           group by 
              tA.ForeignKey,
              tA.Level
           having 
              (SUM(tA.ValueA) / SUM(tA.ValueB) > 0.5) ) PreQualified
      JOIN tableA tA2
         on PreQualified.ForeignKey = tA2.ForeignKey
        AND PreQualified.Level = tA2.Level
```

This would give all values that matched the qualifying condition.